# Static X11 libraries

Tags: ubuntu, xorg

I'd like to compile a full static binary on Ubuntu 13.04 that has X11 as a dependency; I've installed the `-dev` packages (including the `libxaw7-dev`), but can't find a `Xaw.a` library anywhere. Is one available anywhere?

Comment: What compiler (actually, linker) error do you get when you try?

Comment: `/usr/bin/ld: attempted static link of dynamic object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXaw.so'`, although I'm using cmake if that makes a difference.